# Can i modify an html from a frame and save the modifications?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Any way to do this? For example:

Write on a input “Hello”, click a button, and it apears in the other Frame, and modify the text. Then, save it in the document html... i don’t know, with JQuery, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

could you describe it clearly?
1. You can handle event button.click()
2. Frame?
3. Inside the button click event, can also update in another component.

Comment: This should be in the comments' section.